# Cannot invalidate timer in iOS

Tags: ios, timer, invalidation

I'm new to programming, and I've been stuck for a while on the following:

When I run the attached code, everything seems to work fine, then the progress bar starts counting up again.  The console keeps printing the invalidation confirmation string, but the timer seems to keep rolling.  I appreciate your help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize doneYet;
@synthesize cooking;
@synthesize hidebutton;

- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [doneYet setProgress:doneYet.progress=0.0];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setDoneYet:nil];
    [self setHidebutton:nil];
    [self setCooking:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(void)startTimer
{CurrentTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];}

-(void)timerFired

{ if (doneYet.progress<1) {

    [doneYet setProgress:doneYet.progress+0.1];
}

else if (doneYet.progress=1) 

{
    (void) [CurrentTimer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"invalidated CurrentTimer");
    hidebutton.hidden = FALSE;
    cooking.hidden = TRUE;
    [doneYet setProgress:doneYet.progress=0.0];
}
}


- (IBAction)Eggtimer:(id)sender 
{   
    [self startTimer];
    hidebutton.hidden = TRUE;
    cooking.hidden = FALSE;
    ;}    

@end
```

Comment: How many time have you pressed the button which have `Eggtimer` as action

Comment: The button hides after the first time it is pressed.  It then reappears when the progress bar is cleared after reaching 100%. It all looks fine for a second, but then the progress bar starts moving again.  Interestingly enough, the bar will move twice as fast if I then push the button again.

Answer (score 3):

This seems a problem

```
else if (doneYet.progress=1)
```

for 2 reasons:

- the equality comparison operator is `==` and not `=` (which is the assign operator)
- you are comparing a `float` number for an exact value, this is never good because floating numbers are not precise, you should check for `progress >= 1.0`, otherwise you could go over 1.0 (eg 1.0000001) and skip stop condition

In addition in the stop condition you do

```
[doneYet setProgress:doneYet.progress=0.0];
```

but formerly it should be

```
[doneYet setProgress:0.0];
```

Comment: @Jack.. he is just assigning here and I think it's fine if you see it's if condition which compare <1

Comment: @Jack, Thank you so much for your time on this.I made your suggested change from < to <=, and what happened is that the progress bar reaches full, but then everything stops.  The else actions never happen in that the progress bar stays full, the console never receives the timer invalidated string, and the button never unhides.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this, `retain` the `NSTimer` object.

`CurrentTimer=[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES] retain];`

Comment: Hi All, I'm very sorry to tell you this, but I fixed the problem by revoking the "First Responder" designation from the button that (calls? - I don't know the proper term) startTimer.  That corrected it immediately.  **Thanks so much for your time and help with this!**

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is change your startTimer as

```
-(void)startTimer
{
    [CurrentTimer invalidate];
    CurrentTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
}
```

This will invalidate old timer and there will be only one timer.

Answer (score -1):

**My error was in designating the button that commands startTimer as the FirstResponder.**

Sorry for using your time and advice on something that was the result of an error not in the code.

**Thanks again to everyone who offered their advice.  It means a lot to a beginner!**